# Getting distinct values in this query

Tags: php, mysql

Hi, this is my query:

```
  SELECT tbl_order_detail.order_id, tbl_order_lead_send_detail.customer_id, tbl_order_detail.order_title, tbl_order_detail.dealer_id , tbl_order_lead_send_detail.send_date_time
        FROM tbl_order_detail
        INNER JOIN tbl_order_lead_send_detail
        ON tbl_order_detail.order_id=tbl_order_lead_send_detail.order_id
        where tbl_order_detail.order_status='Active'
        ORDER BY tbl_order_lead_send_detail.send_date_time DESC
```

I am getting this output,

[image: Urgent ?]

I want to get only one data-row for one means distinct value of **Order ID**.  How can I change my sql query to get my desired result?

Comment: Your query and output don't seem to match. For a start, your query returns five columns, but your screenshot shows only four columns. Can you explain this difference please? Is one of the columns not used? If so, which one?

Comment: output before and after some suggestions is same. :(
here is the output http://i.imgur.com/d6NOt.png

Comment: It's hardly surprising that none of the answers work. Your question doesn't even make sense. As I already said, your query doesn't match with what you are displaying. Please explain what process you are using to go from the query that returns 5 columns to the results that have only 4 columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT distinct(tbl_order_detail.order_id), tbl_order_lead_send_detail.customer_id, tbl_order_detail.order_title, tbl_order_detail.dealer_id , tbl_order_lead_send_detail.send_date_time
        FROM tbl_order_detail
        INNER JOIN tbl_order_lead_send_detail
        ON tbl_order_detail.order_id=tbl_order_lead_send_detail.order_id
        where tbl_order_detail.order_status='Active'
        ORDER BY tbl_order_lead_send_detail.send_date_time DESC
```

Comment: It doesn't works. Giving same output dude. see result of your query http://i.imgur.com/d6NOt.png

Comment: This is because you're using an INNER JOIN, sorry I should have picked that up earlier. If you're only wanting the order id once I would suggest using a LEFT join instead.

Comment: @Rawcode: Using LEFT instead of INNER, I'm getting same result set

Answer (score 0):

SELECT DISTINCT tbl_order_detail.order_id, ...

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities:

1) Select **distinct** ..

2) Select ... **group by tbl_order_detail.order_id, tbl_order_lead_send_detail.customer_id, tbl_order_detail.order_title, tbl_order_detail.dealer_id , tbl_order_lead_send_detail.send_date_time**

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that even if you use the keyword `distinct` in your query, it'll still return more than one rows for the same order id if at least one of the columns return a different data. 
Your result image shows 4 columns, while your query asked for 5; so, it's not 100% possible to determine where the problem lies. 
That being said, use `select distinct`, and see if it solves your problem. If it doesn't, you might have to remove the column(s) with the different data from the query. 
Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

From some of your screenshots it appears that *customer id* is different for each row. You *need* to show all the output to get sensible answers.

I'm pretty certain **SELECT DISTINCT** isn't broken, so you *must* be selecting non-unique rows.